# В чем разница между коммерческой и свободно распостроняемой лицензией для QT фреймворка?

Tags: лицензирование, qt

В чем разница между коммерческой и свободно распостроняемой лицензией для QT фреймворка?

Comment: вам эту страничку перевести что-ли ? обратитесь на форум переводчиков.

Comment: нет переводить не надо. спасибо за ссылку

Comment: Можно воспользоваться гугловским переводчиком. Он, например, очень интересно переводит на немецкий строку из песни "Три танкиста, три весёлых друга" -- "drei Tanker, drei Homosexuell Freund" (обратный перевод -- "три танкера, три гомосексуальных друга")